# sentiment analysis on movies reviews

Tags: r, svm, text-mining, naivebayes, xgboost

I'm working on a sentiment analysis project to be made with R, on rotten tomatoes movies reviews.
data is a of 2 fields: Review and Label
label is 0 or 1.
After some digging, i found that i have to use the following libraries

```
library("xgboost")
library(tm)
library(e1071)
```

the best result i got on data is 73.85 using svm, but when using xgboost i got a 0.51 which is totally bad.

i want to know in steps how to use tm library to get a sparse matrix with the text feature extraction from the reviews, and what is the best params for the svm, naivebayes and xgboost to predict well.

Comment: This is probably a question for Stats Exchange/Cross Validated.

Comment: @RaphaelK cant understand you or what to do?

Comment: You are asking two questions: "how to use tm library ...," and  "what is the best params ..." For the first question, I would suggest reading SO Q and As about the `tm` package and maybe a little internet searching. Once you have worked on this, if you have a specific question on using `tm` that involves data and code, this is a good place to get answers. Your second question is certainly better asked on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).